# How can I get content a xml tag by type

Tags: javascript, xml, ecmascript-5

I have a xml document. How can I get content of type="work" by Javascript?

```
<tagname type="job">
<tagname type="work">
<tagname type="home">
```

Comment: Did you try something? :)

Comment: I know how get tag, but I dont know how I can get tag of type. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with pure javascript.

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('tagname');
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  if (tags[i].getAttribute('type') == 'work') {
    var content = tags[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(content);
  }
}
```

Basically you need to iterate over all the tags matching the tag name and look for the one whose attribute has the correct value.

Comment: Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tagname'), 0), It is work.